# TypeError at /confirmemail/amlqctnhel/confirmemail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given), why?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Error:

```
TypeError at /confirmemail/amlqctnhel/

confirmemail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmemail/amlqctnhel/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

confirmemail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/user1/djangoblog',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^confirmemail/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/$', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),
```

views.py:

```
def confirmemail(request,token):

user = Users.objects.get(email_token = token)
return render_to_response('confirmemail.html', {'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It will be highly appreciated if someone can help me to fix it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a URLconf, you need to use capturing groups in your regex to achieve positional or keyword arguments in your view. If you use a named capture group, then keyword arguments are used; otherwise, positional arguments are used.

Here is what your `url()` line should look like:

```
url(r'^confirmemail/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/$', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),
# or
url(r'^confirmemail/(?P<token>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/$', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),
```

The first form uses a positional argument (and positional arguments are ordered by the capture groups in the URL). The second form uses a keyword argument, in this case `token`. The second form is more characters but will also be safe against parameter reordering.

Comment: Correct. You need a capture group (`([stuff])` or `(?P<name>[stuff])`)in your URL regex, otherwise Django will have no clue how to populate your view arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You arent capturing a pattern in your url so its not passing a value for your token parameter

```
url(r'^confirmemail/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/$', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),
```

Note i have wrapped your pattern in a capture group

Comment: You missed the parenthesis, which is also the same example shown in the accepted answer.